# Is there a method in Pandas to check if a cell is bolded?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, cell-formatting

I have a column with names. I want to build a list containing all the names from my column that are bolded. Is there a method in Pandas available to do this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("mydatafile.xlsx")
print("Column Headings:")

mylist = []
for i in df.index:
    if df['Names'][i].celltype == bold
        mylist.append(cell)
```

Comment: as far as I know, dataframes have no formats. Stylers do. Also, please adhere to the guidelines and post a [Reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pandas` does not read styles from Excel. You will have to use another library that does. One such library is [styleframe](https://github.com/deepspace2/StyleFrame) (full disclosure, I'm one of the authors of this library).

Then, using this code

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame
# 'from StyleFrame import StyleFrame' in older versions (< 3.0)

sf = StyleFrame.read_excel('test.xlsx', read_style=True, use_openpyxl_styles=False)

for name in sf.Names:
    if name.style.bold:
        print(name)
```

With this Excel sheet:

[image]

Outputs

```
bold
bold
```

Comment: Now it's `from styleframe import StyleFrame`

Comment: @Pluto indeed. I updated the answer to reflect that change